# Preventing A Thread From Ending

Tags: c#, multithreading

I understand that a Thread will terminate when all of the code it has been assigned is done, but how can I make it so that it stays around waiting for an event? Here is a simple look at my code so you can understand better what my problem is:

```
public static class TimeUpdater
{

        static TimeUpdater()
        {
            //Initialize the Timer object
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000; 
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }

        public static void StartTimer()
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        private static void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something          
        }

}
```

From the main Thread, here is how I am calling these methods:

```
        Thread timeThread = new Thread(TimeUpdater.StartTimer);
        timeThread.Name = "Time Updater";

        timeThread.Start();
```

What this does is it goes inside the `StartTimer()` method, runs it, and then the thread terminates without ever entering the `timer_Tick` event handler. If I call `StartTimer()` from the main thread it works fine.

Anyone can spot the problem? Cheers.

Comment: Why are you using a thread *and* a timer? Why not just use a timer or just a thread?

Comment: I am using both a thread and a timer because I want the operation to run on a secondary thread every 1 second.

Comment: You mean a third thread? You already have a secondary thread, the thread you started. The timer will run on yet another thread. Is this what you want? If so, the answer is probably to make the first thread wait for an event object (ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent) and have the timer tick event signal that event object.

Comment: Why not just make the thread you created wait 1 second before doing its stuff?

Comment: Hi guys, I did not know that the Timer object runs on its own thread. I made it use `Thread.Sleep()` instead and it works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the timer on a separate thread. Starting a timer is a very fast operation. That's why your thread completes immediately. Tick events are started on the thread-pool asynchronously when the time is due.

If you want a thread wait for something then you should insert code into the thread procedure to wait on something. At the moment you do not wait for anything.

If you want to run the timer procedure, just call it.

Comment: I cannot just call the timer procedure, I want it to run every 1 second. How can I make it wait? Sorry I am new to multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I didn't need to use a `Timer` object. Here is how I made it work:

```
    public static void StartTimer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            UpdateTime();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

In your `StartTimer` method you can spin around an infinite loop and call `Thread.Sleep` to delay execution when needed. I see you have already figured that out though. An alternate idea is to use a timer, but instead of starting it from a worker thread start it from the main thread. You really do not need to be manually creating threads at all here.